# How to display database in php in order to show it in android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a problem displaying a mysql database running in XAMPP server, I typed a code which connect perfectly but it doesn't show anything in the php page which didn't let me retrive the data to android app.

Here's my sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` VARCHAR ( 32 ) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR( 1024 ) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

)ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

And my php code :

```
<?php

$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'qrtest';

$dbname = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $dbname) or die ("unable to connect");

echo"connected succesfully!";

mysql_select_db("qrtest", $dbname) or die("can not connect to the database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products")or die("cannot select the table");


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    output[] = $row;
}
print(json_encode($output));

echo"encoding done";

mysql_close($dbname);


?>
```

It should've shown me this:

```
[{"id":"Coca Cola 1L", "description":"qsfjqskdfjqksdffqsdfdf"},{"id":"Ramy 1L","description":"azeazerzertzertzty"},....etc ]
```

But instead it just show those messages:

```
 connected succesfully!encoding done
```

So please i really need a help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, it's `$output`, not `output`. Try the following:

```
$output = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[] = $row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

Your mySQL statement is also invalid. I think you mean:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1
```

not

```
SELECT * FROM products
```

Comment: Yeah i did it but nothing changed. still the same problem.

Comment: Can you try turning on error reporting and check if your mysql statement is valid?

Comment: it's working now i just had descriptions written in french, so i changed the letters "é,è,à, ..." to normal ones, i dont know why those letters made a problem, but thanks Huey, i appreciate your help.